# firefox addon: quit-application observer not working

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I've been trying to use observers for a while now, but it seems like I cannot get them to work. I put the observe function in different modules of my extension, and also different parts of my code. Registering it from everywhere but it seems like every way that I tried was just a deadened. I can't get it to work. My goal is to listen for when a user exits from Firefox so I can clear preferences objects of my addon. As of now my observer is in bootstrap.js, and this is how I implemented it. I implemented my observe function this way because it was mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477222/firefox-addon-not-able-to-listen-firefox-quit-application-event) stackoverflow post that this is the right way to observe for quit-application notification. On a side note observers registered gets printed in console log but "oh observing" doesn't.

```
function myObserver()
{
  this.register();
}
myObserver.prototype = {
  observe: function(subject, topic, data) {
    console.log("oh observing!!");

  if (topic == "app-startup" || topic == "profile-after-change") {
     var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                                     .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
     observerService.addObserver(this, "quit-application", false);
   }

    else if (topic == "quit-application-requested" || topic == "quit-application")
    {
    console.log("browser closing");
    alert('hello');
    myextension.Utils.prefService.clearUserPref("questionType");
    myextension.Utils.prefService.clearUserPref("clickThrough");
    this.unregister();
    }
  },

  register: function() {

            var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
                .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);

            observerService.addObserver(this, "quit-application-requested",false);
            observerService.addObserver(this, "quit-application",false);
            observerService.addObserver(this, "app-startup", false);
            observerService.addObserver(this, "profile-after-change", false);
            console.log("observers registered");

  },

     unregister: function() {
        var observerService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/observer-service;1"]
            .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIObserverService);
        observerService.removeObserver(this, "quit-application-requested");
        console.log("unregistering obs");
    }
}
```

This is my startup function:

```
    function startup(data, reason) {
      Components.utils.import("chrome://ext/content/commons.jsm");
      let wm = Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].
               getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator);

      let windows = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");
      while (windows.hasMoreElements()) {
        let domWindow = windows.getNext().QueryInterface(Ci.nsIDOMWindow);

        WindowListener.setupBrowserUI(domWindow);

      }

  // Wait for any new browser windows to open
  wm.addListener(WindowListener);

}
```

and this is my setupBrowserUI function in which I register the observer:

```
  setupBrowserUI: function(domWindow) {
    extension.onLoad(domWindow.gBrowser);
    observer = new myObserver();
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm

```
let observer = {
  observe: function() {
         dump("oh observing")
  }
};

function startup(data, reason)
{
  Services.obs.addObserver(observer, "*", false);
  observer.observe();
}
```

My suggest is create a log file with the preferences; to output dump calls instead to a file, set *browser.dom.window.dump.file* to the file destination where the log should be created and restart the application.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/Preference_reference/browser.dom.window.dump.file